# How to store cell positions(row,column) in Java?

Tags: java, excel, csv, collections

I've to store some cell positions in an excel file to be compared later.
ex. (1,6) (1,17) (2,6) (2,17). where 1 -> row, 6 -> column

I can't figure out which collection to use in Java for this.

There must be a mapping present between the two values. I can't use a map because the key values are not unique. I don't want to use multidimensional arrays as they get too complicated.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to map a single row value to multiple column values, you could use a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` or a `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>`, and create a kind of [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list). Then, having the row value, you would be able to retrieve all corresponding column values. To make it easier to use, you could wrap it with a custom class like this:

```
class Positions {
    private Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> positions = new HashMap<>();

    void add(int row, int column) {
        Set<Integer> columns = this.columnsFromRow(row);
        columns.add(column);
        this.positions.put(row, columns);
    }

    Set<Integer> columnsFromRow(int row) {
        Set<Integer> columns = this.positions.get(row);
        if (columns == null) {
            columns = new HashSet<>();
        }
        return columns;
    }

    boolean isTherePosition(int row, int column) {
        return this.columnsFromRow(row).contains(column);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
This would be nice, except that my purpose here is different. I need a mapping between a single row value with multiple column values. It's like if I have the row value, it should return all corresponding column values. 
Actually, If I try, I can use your class for my purpose, but I was trying to avoid creating a custom class. For now, I tried using Map<Integer, Integer[]> and it's kind of working for me. 
What way would be better as per you?

Comment: Now I see what you meant when you said that there must be a mapping between the two values. In this case, I think what you're doing, using a Map<Integer, Integer[]> or a Map<Integer, List<Integer>> is the way to go.